# Why DragLeave isn't triggered when drag drop effect is DragDropEffects.Link?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to make a program that allows to drag and drop files to a `ListView`. I use `ListView.InsertionMark` to identify where to insert file. When I drop the file, the `InsertionMark` doesn't disappear because the `DragLeave` event isn't triggered; if I change drag drop effect to `DragDropEffects.None`, the `DragLeave` event is triggered when I release the mouse. Why is this happening?

Also, the document says "If there is a change in the keyboard or mouse button state, the `QueryContinueDrag` event is raised and determines whether to continue the drag, to drop the data, or to cancel the operation based on the value of the `Action` property of the event's `QueryContinueDragEventArgs`." But the `QueryContinueDrag` event is also not triggered.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private ListView listView1 = new ListView();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Controls.Add(listView1);

        listView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.Columns.Add("Test");
        listView1.Items.Add("0");
        listView1.AllowDrop = true;

        listView1.DragEnter += listView1_DragEnter;
        listView1.DragOver += listView1_DragOver;
        listView1.DragLeave += listView1_DragLeave;
        listView1.DragDrop += listView1_DragDrop;
        listView1.GiveFeedback += listView1_GiveFeedback;
        listView1.QueryContinueDrag += listView1_QueryContinueDrag;
    }

    private void listView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Link | DragDropEffects.Scroll;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
    }

    private void listView1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        // This is not done, only to show this problem.
        listView1.InsertionMark.Index = 0;
        listView1.InsertionMark.AppearsAfterItem = true;
    }

    private void listView1_DragLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.InsertionMark.Index = -1;
    }

    private void listView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        // listView1.InsertionMark.Index = -1; // Is this really necessary?
    }

    private void listView1_QueryContinueDrag(object sender, QueryContinueDragEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = "listView1_QueryContinueDrag";
    }

    private void listView1_GiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = "listView1_GiveFeedback";
    }
}
```

Do I have to set `listView1.InsertionMark.Index = -1` manually to hide the `InsertionMark`? Is there anyway to trigger the `DragLeave` event when drag drop effect is `DragDropEffects.Link`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I drop the file, the `InsertionMark` doesn't disappear because the `DragLeave` event isn't triggered;

[`DragLeave`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragleave.aspx):

> The `DragLeave` event is raised when the user **drags the cursor out of the control** or the user **cancels the current drag-and-drop operation**.

(Emphasis added)

They did neither - they completed the drop. Why are you so surprised that this event didn't fire then?

---

Re: [`QueryContinueDrag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.querycontinuedrag):

> The `QueryContinueDrag` event enables the **drag source** to determine whether the drag-and-drop operation should be canceled.

(Emphasis added)

I could be wrong here, but in this instance, you appear to be the drag target, not the source.

Comment: But if I don't set `e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Link | DragDropEffects.Scroll`, when drop a file, the `DragLeave` event does be triggered.

Comment: @EFanZh - If you're talking about the branch of your code where you set the effect to `None` instead, then no drop operation can occur. That effectively forces the operation to be cancelled if they release the mouse button.